# How can we define the set $\{\{\}, \{\{\}\}, \{\{\{\}\}\}, ...\}$?

Tags: logic, set-theory

How do you define the set of elements which can be made by repeatedly wrapping the null set in another set: $\{\{\}, \{\{\}\}, \{\{\{\}\}\}, ...\}$?

I've tried $A = \{x\ |\ x=\emptyset \lor \exists y\in A : x = \{y\}\}$, but that would give us a recursive formula, because $y\in A$ is replaced by that same formula.

Is this set definable, and if yes, how?

Comment: I’d do it by first setting $x_0=\varnothing$ and recursively defining $x_{n+1}=\{x_n\}$ and then letting $A=\{x_n:n\in\omega\}$. You’ll need the recursion theorem in some form here.

Comment: What is $\omega$?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD $\omega=\Bbb N$, basically. (In fact, in set theory, we have $\omega=\Bbb N=\aleph_0$. _Everything_ is a set in ZFC, so $\aleph_0$ is represented by a canonical set with that cardinality.) Also, $0\in\omega$ unambiguously. (In set theory, $0=\{\}$, for the same reason.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:
$$\{x\mid\forall A,(\{\}\in A\land(\forall a\in A,\\\{a\}\in A))\Rightarrow x\in A\}$$
To make that easier to read, let me define the following. A set $A$ is *upwards* if $a\in A$ implies $\{a\}\in A$. (I made up this word just now.) A set $A$ is called *totally upwards* if it's upwards and it contains $\{\}$. (I also just made this up.) Then the above reads:
$$\{x\mid\forall A,\\A\text{ is totally upwards }\Rightarrow x\in A\}$$

Comment: I'd also write that as $\bigcap\{A:A\text{ is totally upwards}\}$, using the convention that $\bigcap X$ means the intersection of everything in $X$.

Answer (score 1):

What axioms of set theory are you using?  The existence of an infinite set is independent of the other axioms.

ZFC usually takes the axiom of infinity to be something like

$$
\exists Z ( \emptyset \in Z \wedge \forall x \in Z (x \cup \{x\} \in Z) )
$$

but your axiom would be just as good.

Do you see how to use my axiom to construct the set you are looking for?

Comment: I think the question is about how to even _define_ the set precisely in set-builder notation, not how to prove it exists from some particular axioms.

Comment: @EricWofsey I am not sure:  the OP is not particularly clear about what kinds of descriptions they admit.  In any case, I think at some point your set builder notation must make use of some countably infinite set.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, because there's an axiom that says you can do exactly that, because you *can't* derive it from the intuitively more "basic" axioms. It is called the axiom of infinity, and states that there is a non-empty set $S$ such that whenever $X \in S$, then $(\{X\} \cup X) \in S$ as well.

Comment: The axiom of infinity guaranteed a slightly different set. Specifically, it guarantees an _inductive set_, which you just defined. OP's set is not inductive.

Comment: I think the question is about how to even _define_ the set precisely in set-builder notation, not how to prove it exists from some particular axioms.